# Angularjs two form for the same controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with angularjs code. I have a roles select replicated in two modal: create user and change role.
This select is filled with http call in this way:

```
<ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
    data-ng-model="newUser.role" required> 
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select role">
       {{$select.selected.role}}
    </ui-select-match> 
    <ui-select-choices
       repeat="role.idRole as role in (roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.role">
       <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

and in angular I have:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'roles'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.roles = response.data.result;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

So I put the HTML code inside form in two modal.
In the first, create user, all works fine, in the second I can't use a different data-ng-model because otherwise I receive undifined element. For example I have this:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form" name="newRoleForm">
    <!-- form start -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>New role</label>
            <!-- <ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
                data-ng-model="newRole.role" required> <ui-select-match
                placeholder="Select new role">
            {{$select.selected.role}}</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
                repeat="role.idRole as role in (roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.role">
            <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select> -->
            <ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
                data-ng-model="newUser.role" required> <ui-select-match
                placeholder="Select role">
            {{$select.selected.role}}</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
                repeat="role.idRole as role in (roles | filter: $select.search) track by role.role">
            <span data-ng-bind="role.role"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I use commented code I don't receive in my javascript the role value, if I use the uncommented code it works because newUser is used in the other modal.
I could use this actual code, but I would like to understand why it works and the other no.
Furthermore when I open the second modal I see the value setted in the first.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little tricky to get a perfect overview but I think I'll try to answer few of your questions:

1. Why doesn't `newRole.role` work when `newUser.role` does?

   Basically you answered this yourself from what I can tell. You need to define the object somewhere in your scope before starting to bind properties to it. Ie a simple `$scope.newRole = {}` in your controller might fix this error.
2. Value from the first modal is set in the second one?

   I'm not sure about this as I cant see this second modal (?). But if you reuse the same code in the same scope you will bind data to the same newUser object. Hence getting the same values each time.

I hope this helped in some way

Comment: For the first question I never define newUser, I only pass it from Web page to angularjs function. I'll try to use plnkr